# Hiding rows is extremely slow

Tags: excel, vba, show-hide

I'm having issues with hiding the rows from a sheet, and I was hoping I could get some advice.
The sheet has 1380 rows in total, and it goes until column DM, so it's not huge.
The 1380 rows are split into sections recognized by named ranges (eg GOTO_GA) inside a name range that contains everything (_FilterDatabase), and I need to show each section individually by clicking some buttons on top. I do this by hiding _FilterDatabase and unhiding only GOTO_GA.

The problem is, even if i'm turning everything that i can think of off, see code below,  `rngToHide.Hidden = True` is still extremely slow, 30 seconds.

Is there anything else I could look into to speed it up?

```
Sub testHideRows()
    Dim rngToHide As Range, rngToShow As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

    Set rngToHide = Range("_FilterDatabase").EntireRow  '1273   ROWS
    Set rngToShow = Range("GOTO_GA").EntireRow          '16 ROWS , INCLUDED IN rngToShow
    TIME0 = Now()
    rngToHide.Hidden = True                             'THIS IS EXTREMLY SLOW 28 SECONDS
    TIME1 = Now()
    Debug.Print Format(TIME1 - TIME0, "hh:NN:SS")
    rngToShow.Hidden = False                            'THIS IS INSTANT

    setProgramAlertsOn
End Sub
```

I've ran the below tests to try to pin point the issue (to re-iterate, I've only taken over the template, I did not do it, so i need to test things out):

1. I removed all conditional formatting to see if it's coming from here, and hiding rows is equally slow.
2. I've restored the file and replaced all formulas with values, and the processing time went down to about 3 seconds from 30, so it's most definitely something in the formulas that is slowing it down.

**But now I ask you guys: Application.Calculation is set to xlCalculationManual, so what formulas still calculate in this case?**

Comment: I can't reproduce this slowness with any test range I've used. Its all fast for me. Could you share with us the Range.Address value of  `_FilterDatabase`? Just wondering if there is anything unusual about this range.

Comment: Can you also qualify `Range` in `Range("GOTO_GA").EntireRow` to a worksheet? I am not 100% sure it will help here, but it's also just best practice for optimal code execution (and error free coding).

Comment: Agree, I can't reproduce this in O365. Using this macro, a  continuous range of 1300 rows for _FilterDatabase, and an non-continuous range of 10 rows for the show, there is 00:00:00 time elapsed

Comment: _FilterDatabase is a simple named range created by the previous developer, that leads to a static address. The only thing special about it is that it's named range .hidden property is set to true, so i don't see it in Formulas - Name manager, do you think this could cause issues?

Comment: See if there's any subscription to the worksheet change event or any other types of event. Toggle a breakpoint at this line - rngToHide.Hidden = True , and then run one step at a time, see if there's any VBA code triggered after setting the range to hidden.

Comment: Do you have any Conditional Formatting on your worksheet?

Comment: @LuanYi Should anithing trigger on hiding rows if i have "Application.EnableEvents = False" ? I guess what i'm asking is, are there exceptions that trigger even if EnableEvents are off, and Calculation is set to manual?

Comment: Apologies, I missed that line :(. Couple of points: 1. Application.EnableEvents = False only disable workbook and worksheet events. But in your case I suppose it is not the issue; 2. If the hidden rows relate to other worksheets, or Charts (especially), then other calculations are still likely to fire up even when setting calculations to manual; 3. Try using "Worksheets("XXX").EnableCalculation = False" on a sheet-by-sheet basis to see if you can turn off calculations completely.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Excel 2016.
Setting

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
Application.EnableEvents = False 
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
```

didn't help.

What DID help was determining the range of rows that should be shown/hidden and doing it in one step, so I have a loop determining which rows should have the Hidden property changed to True/False respectively as rg_to_hide/rg_to_show, and after the loop, if determined ranges are not Nothing, I change the Hidden property of all rows of the determined range.
In case of my data I reduced the execution time from about 25 to 2 seconds.

Best regards and good luck!